# How to retrieve data from Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, snapshot

I am trying to retrieve every object stored in Firebase. Not sure how to go ahead. The following is my code and snap.value printed. I need to retrieve String "cbc" and "cp24" as well as values for datasaved and url.   "cbc" and "cp24" are names I entered when saving.

```
Ref_UsersBase.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

 if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshots {

                print(snap.value)


            }              
        }
    })

{
```

// Here is snap.value printed:

```
{
"-KGOzXm1lLtyS23cOR-G" =     {
    cp24 =         {
        datesaved = "Apr 27, 2016";
        url = "https://www.google.ca/search?site=&source=hp&ei=H0chV6pfhKeOBJChpqAN&q=cp24+weather&oq=&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.1.0.41l2.0.0.0.13343.1.1.0.1.1.0.368.368.3-1.1.0....0...1..64.mobile-gws-hp..0.1.6.2.JC6OI95nuYc";
    };
};
"-KGOznhRN0J2OVlIogZ0" =     {
    cbc =         {
        datesaved = "Apr 27, 2016";
        url = "http://www.cbc.ca/beta/news/canada/toronto";
    };
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I have done in a similar situation, I hope it helps you.

I declare a variable to store snapshot.value, a first array to store the keys at the first level ("-KGOzXm1lLtyS23cOR-G") and a second array to store the keys at second level ("cp24").

```
var receivedData = [String:[String:[String:String]]]()
var firstKeyArray = [String]()
var secondKeyArray = [String]()
```

I store the whole snapshot.value in receivedData.

```
Ref_UsersBase.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    self.receivedData = snapshot.value    
})
```

Fill firstKeyArray and secondKeyArray

```
var i = 0

for(key,_) in receivedData{
    firstKeyArray.append(key)
    for(key,_) in receivedData[firstKeyArray[i]]!{
        secondKeyArray.append(key)
    }
    i += 1
}
```

Finally you would access datesaved and url values like this

```
print(receivedData[firstKeyArray[0]]![secondKeyArray[0]]!["datesaved"]!)

//prints Apr 27
```

Comment: Thanks, man. The method for firstKeyArray works.           for(key,_) in receivedData[firstKeyArray[i]]{
    secondKeyArray.append(key)
}           does not work. Error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [String : [String : String]]]'  with an index of type   'ArraySlice<String>'

Comment: Sorry, I had a few mistakes and edited my answer, I did a playground simulating the snapshot you are getting from firebase and successfully printed "datesaved". Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks man. I notices those mistakes when I was coding and have modified it. I got The same error. I am guessing because "cbc" and "cp24" are names I entered when saving, so can't get it as key. Sometimes working in playground doesn't mean will be working in real app.

Comment: Hi valencieu, I worked out the whole thing according to your clue of firstkey so I accepted your answer. Have a nice weekend!